# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and external RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I deployed an app on EBS and I have a RDS instance. My app works fine, but cannot connect to RDS, so I navigate to security groups and check the default-sg (same as RDS is in) and add a inbound rule for the 2 security groups that my EBS app is in, and it not work, my app still doesn't connect.

My next step was to go on EC2 and copy the public EC2 ip from the EC2 that EBS creates, remove the 2 security groups from EBS in the inbound and add the IP from EC2 as inbound rules, and it started working, my app communicates with the RDS database.

Strangely it keeps working, if I remove the rule, it still communicates without the rule. I don't know what is going on. Any place I read says to add the EBS SG to the RDS SG as inbound rule.

Can someone explain what is going and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are they in the same VPC?

Comment: when I go on the configuration on EBS enviroment in network it says "This environment is not part of a VPC.", but the, EC2 is part of the same VPC as RDS. I deployed the same app with the environment configured for the same VPC and the same situation occurred

Comment: Adding the security group of the EC2 instance as an allowed source for a rule in the RDS security group is all you should have to do.